# Portable way to kill a process listening on a given port

Tags: networking, process, cygwin

Is there a way to kill a process listening on a given port (e.g. in `bash` `lsof -t -i tcp:8000 | xargs kill`) from a shell script that will also work on `cygwin`, as well as `bash`?

Comment: Cygwin as well as bash? Cygwin runs bash just fine. O.o

Comment: None of those commands are part of bash. Well, the `|` is but that is 100% portable. What error are you getting? How does it fail? Do you have `lsof` and `xargs` installed on your Cygwin?

Comment: Does that scriptlet not work on cygwin?

Comment: Right... I was not very precise: the 'lsof' command (which indeed is not bash) is found only on some "UNIX dialects" (this is the wording used by 'man lsof'). Cygwin does not recognize it as a command (while 'kill' and 'xargs' seem to be recognized). Is there an equivalent one-liner (using or not using 'kill' and 'xargs') that will achieve on Cygwin the same result as the command I mentioned in my question?

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, `lsof` has not been ported to cygwin.

You could use the Microsoft `netstat` utility there:

```
netstat -aon | awk '$1 == "TCP" && $4 == "LISTENING" && $2 ~ /:8000$/ {print $5}' |
  xargs kill
```

Answer (score 0):

The initial part of the problem of killing processes that are listening on a given port is identifying the process. `lsof` isn't available on Cygwin, but the `fuser` tool is (as part of the `psmisc` package) and is documented in its man page as:

> fuser - identify processes using files or sockets

There is a demonstration in the EXAMPLES section of the manual that shows

> fuser telnet/tcp shows all processes at the (local) TELNET port.

(You may need to run your cygwin shell as an administrator.)